# How to Reload App dot Component in ANGULAR 7

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Basically, I want to reload my app component after updating my database in firebase.
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true});
navigate property just load component I want to reload app component for some time.
How I can do it?

Comment: Do you want to reload your `app.component` or reload the `data`? If first, then why? If second, you shoud use a data service to deal with the data and pass the data to component. The component does not always need to be aware what the data is.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want you to reload component if data changes? SPA is not intended for reloading.
Angular listens to data change and re-renders the view automatically. If you want to execute some function after data change, then call that functions.